# How to put lambda function result payload in specific result path and keep all previous data

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I pass the following json to AWS Lambda function

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level2_a": {
            "data1": "data1",
            "data2": "data2"
        },
        "level2_b": 42
    }
}
```

The output payload of the lambda contains following data

```
    "Payload": {
        "data1": "data1_changed",
        "data2": "data2_changed"
    }
```

I want to replace "level2" value with the one in the "Payload"
If I put in the ASL file for the lambda

```
"ResultSelector": {
    "level2_a.$": "$.Payload"
},
"ResultPath": "$.level1"
```

The following output

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level2_a": {
            "data1": "data1",
            "data2": "data2"
        }
    }
}
```

where `"level2_b": 42` is missing

How to implement configure the lambda function in the step function ASL file, so at the end to have the output merged, like the following json

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level2_a": {
            "data1": "data1_changed",
            "data2": "data2_changed"
        },
        "level2_b": 42
    }
}
```

I tried also

```
"ResultSelector": {
    "$": "$.Payload"
},
"ResultPath": "$.level1.level2_a"
```

but `"$": "$.Payload"` is not working

Also tried this

```
"ResultSelector": "$.Payload",
"ResultPath": "$.level1.level2_a"
```

again no success

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys of your object are static, this should give you what you want:

```json
      "ResultSelector": {
        "data1.$": "$.Payload.data1",
        "data2.$": "$.Payload.data2"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.level1.level2_a"
```

Comment: No, the keys are not static

Comment: @DanielSapoundjiev is there a reason you can't return your desired payload from the Lambda itself?

Comment: The desired output is returned by the lambda - some data. Lambda puts the returned data in Payload object. But the issue is not what Lamda returns, it is that you cannot merge it to the Output data without loosing some data or using extra element

Comment: @DanielSapoundjiev but why can’t you return the entire output from the Lambda since you pass everything you need into it?

Comment: The Task result contains metadata, status code, executed versions automatically added to the result. You are right, if there was no extra data, I could just put everything using ResultPath and not using the ResultSelector

Comment: @DanielSapoundjiev if you set the OutputPath as ‘$.Payload’ all of that will be filtered away.